# How do I make a symmetric matrix using R?

Tags: r, matrix, symmetric

I am trying to make a symmetric matrix using R.
I already have a matrix. My matrix is very big so below is a simple example.

EX.

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

I need to make them like this.

1    2+4  3+7

4+2  5   6+8

7+3  8+6   9

//So I tried this. // mat is the matrix I am using.

`lowervector <- square_07[lower.tri(square_07, diag = FALSE)]`

`uppervector <- square_07[upper.tri(square_07, diag = FALSE)]`

`lowermat <- square_07`
`uppermat <- square_07`

`lowermat[lower.tri(lowermat, diag = FALSE)] <- t(square_07)[lower.tri(square_07, diag = FALSE)]`

`uppermat[upper.tri(uppermat, diag = FALSE)] <- t(square_07)[upper.tri(square_07, diag = FALSE)]`

When I execute the last 2 lines, an error occurs;

*Subscript 'upper.tri(uppermat, diag = FALSE)' is a matrix, the data 't[upper.tri(square_07, diag = FALSE)]' must have size 1.*

**You should know. The upper matrix is just an example. My actual matrix is much more bigger. It is a 248*248 matrix.**

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I need to add the values of the two sides around the center line of the matrix...!
The center line's values are 1, 5, 9. So 2 and 4 should be added together. And 3 and 7, 6 and 8 should be added together also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- mat[upper.tri(mat)] + mat[lower.tri(mat)]
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- mat[upper.tri(mat)]
mat

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    6   10
#[2,]    6    5   14
#[3,]   10   14    9
```

**data**

```
mat <- structure(c(1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 9L), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
mat

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    4    5    6
#[3,]    7    8    9
```

Comment: I think this is a more simple solution if it works...Thank you!
But the problem is this code also occurs an error message. 
**Subscript `upper.tri(square_07)` is a matrix, the data `square_07[upper.tri(square_07)] + square_07[lower.tri(square_07)]` must have size 1.**

Comment: square_07 is my matrix

Comment: What is `class(square_07)` and what is `dim(square_07)` ?

Comment: class is data frame. 
class(square_07)     "tbl_df"      "tbl"     "data.frame"
dimension is 248*248

Comment: class of square_07[upper.tri(square_07)] is numeric

Comment: But dimension of square_07[upper.tri(square_07)] is NULL....
However square_07[upper.tri(square_07)] has numeric values in it.

Comment: @Mir First convert `square_07` to matrix. `square_07 <- as.matrix(square_07)` and then try the answer.

Comment: Oh..I guess I didn't know the difference between data frames and matrices. Thank you so much! The problem is solved.

Answer (score 6):

This is simpler:

```
result <- square_07 + t(square_07)
diag(result) <- diag(square_07)
result
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    6   10
# [2,]    6    5   14
# [3,]   10   14    9
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to it the transpose (giving you the desired off-diagonal elements) and subtract the diagonal (because the previous operation will double your diagonal elements):

```
desired.matrix <- matrix + t(matrix) - diag(diag(matrix))
```

The reason for the iterated `diag` commands is because the first diag will just give you a vector. The second `diag` will result to the desired matrix w/c you want to subract.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be something like below:

```
# make square matrix of 16 elements
M <- matrix(data=sample(1:16), nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=FALSE)

# make the matrix symmetric
MS <- 1/2 * (M + t(M))

# check if matrix is symmetric
isSymmetric(MS)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try `igraph` to interpret the matrix as an adjacency matrix of a graph

```
library(igraph)
mat %>%
  graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mode = "plus") %>%
  get.adjacency()
```

which gives

```
[1,]  1  6 10
[2,]  6  5 14
[3,] 10 14  9
```

## data

```
mat <- structure(c(1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 9L), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
```